# SVG: Use Attributes or CSS to style?

Tags: coding-style, svg

In HTML it is recommended to seperate Content from Style, thus you should create external CSS-Files for your styles. As I am just getting started with SVG I now wonder: Does this rule also apply for SVG?

What is considered better code style?

- `<circle fill="yellow" />`
- or `<circle style="fill: yellow;" />`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I would generally prefer `<circle fill="yellow" />` to `<circle style="fill: yellow;" />` because it's shorter and easily to manipulate with, for example, `getAttributeNS(null, "fill")`.

But over that I would prefer using a separate style element, just as with HTML, e.g:

```
  <style>
    circle{
      fill: yellow;
    }
  </style>
```

Which has all the same advantages of using CSS, such as making it easy to change the stlye of lots of elements at once.

You can also put your CSS in an external file and add:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="your_CSS.css" ?>
```

Before the svg element.

Comment: This also has the advantage that it can potentially make you SVG files a lot smaller by replacing each repeating attribute with a single style.

Answer (score 40):

I arrived here because I was trying to remember whether attributes or styles have greater precedence. This is one practical reason why you'd want one over another.

Attributes get applied as "presentation hints", as if they were the first of the cascading style sheets. [In other words, this gives them lowest precedence.](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-CSS2-20080411/cascade.html#q12)

Thus the precedence, from lowest to highest, is

1. attributes
2. CSS style sheets
3. inline styles

It's a little confusing that an inline style has much greater precedence than the attribute it's next to. (I keep having to look this up!)

There aren't going to be any new presentation attributes, and we are encouraged to use CSS styling instead, but it doesn't sound like presentation attributes are going away anytime soon.

More detail can be found in the [Presentation Attributes section of the Styling chapter of the SVG standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#PresentationAttributes).

Answer (score 13):

I have found [Presentation Attributes vs Inline Styles on css-trick](https://css-tricks.com/presentation-attributes-vs-inline-styles/) really useful for this.

From it:

[image: An image showing that css rules override attributes, but not inline style unless they include important]

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but [your second claim is incorrect](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/kpcgL3jz/) and contradicts the infographic.

Comment: OMG @Gordon, you are right! And thanks for pointing this out. I've edited my answer to remove that claim. Here's a fiddle to show you're right: https://jsfiddle.net/Izhaki/kphg4zLm/

Answer (score 4):

The difference is always if it's content or it's presentation.

If the circle is content and it has to show whether or not there css available, then the first option is the one.

But if the circle is just part of the site disign and doesn't add anything to the content, then it should be the second option. Or use a css class.

Comment: Good Argument but I’d rephrase that somewhat: If the fact that the circle is yellow is content (a drawing of a character from “The Simpsons”, perhaps), it should be an attribute; if the fact that the circle is yellow is purely accidental (and can be ascribed to the fact that the rest of the publication uses a lot of yellow), it should be in CSS.